# Summation with 3 binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

In the book "Concrete Mathematics" by Knuth there is a binomial coefficient identity

$\sum_{k} {a+b \choose a+k}{b+c \choose b+k}{c+a \choose c+k}(-1)^k=\frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!b!c!}$

but no proof is given. Can someone at least guide me to a way to prove it?

Comment: Please read the Wikipedia aritcle [Wilf-Zeilberger pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) for a technique designed for this kind of problem.

Comment: I do not see any identity here. There is even no equal sign...

Comment: Sorry I forgot it and it is edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Dixon's summation theorem for terminating ${}_{3}F_{2}$ hypergeometric series. A very elementary self-contained proof is given in my article ["An algebraic independence result related to a conjecture of Dixmier on binary form invariants"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11147). The relevant part is from the bottom of page 5 to the middle of page 8 and no need to read anything else in the article.